# Rails multiple has_many through and has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried to find the answer to this for Rails4 but all similar questions have different situation .. When I do this

```
class Law < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
    has_many :categories, -> { uniq }, through: :statutes
    has_many :categories, -> { uniq }, through: :sections
```

you can see that Law gets categories from 3 different sources. But it just reads the last one and show me the categories through sections. How do I merge the above three statements. (I am skipping other relationships in this model).

Answer (score 0):

Your last association will overwrite the two previous ones, because they have the same name. You can name your associations differently to get around this, e.g.:

```
class Law < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_many :status_categories, -> { uniq }, through: :statutes, source: :categories
  has_many :section_categories, -> { uniq }, through: :sections, source: :categories
```